# LTO3 tape volume appears to be smaller than 800GB

Tags: backup, backupexec, lto-3

I am using BackupExec and it is asking for second tape. I am using LTO-3 ultrium 800 gig 2:1 compression tapes and it stops and asks for secound tape at 558,916,035,547  Byte count. Is my setup wrong or do i just need to get larger tapes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LTO 3 has 800 GB capacity at the assumed compression ratio of 2:1, which is very optimistic in most cases. The physical capacity is 400GB, and in my experience a compression ration between 1.1:1 to 1.5:1 is much more realistic, but that is very much dependent on your data.

If you have an LTO4 drive, you could also use LTO4 tapes which have double the capacity. LTO-5 is the current generation with 1.5TB native capacity, but these drives can only read LTO3 tapes, not write them.

For more info, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape-Open).

Comment: thank you for the response that is what i thought ordered bigger tapes .   :)

Comment: +1. Actually you may have a backup software already compressing which then means the tape has little left to compress ;)

Comment: @volcer: Using LTO4 tapes is only working if you have an LTO4 drive, so be sure to check your drive type.

Answer (score 3):

What that means is that you get 800GB when the compression is 2:1. You must be getting less than 2:1 compression so that's why you're only getting 550GB or so on your tape. Nothing is wrong with your setup.

Comment: thank you so much for the response i thought that was the reason